# Simple nativescript-community/ui-mapbox question: how to move things?

Tags: mapbox

I've been wanting to simply **move a marker or a feature** using nativescript-community/ui-mapbox.
Problem is I can't figure out **how to retrieve the source** (using getSource) or the **style** to then be able to get my feature and update its coordinates.

Do you have an idea how moving things is supposed to be done in this library?

Note that I don't use Typescript and I can't use the marker.update().

Thank you!

---

Here's a bit of code to explain the problem:

```js
var source = {
       'type': 'geojson',
       'data':  {'type': 'Point',
                'coordinates': [50.1, 3.4]}
}

mapbox.addSource('my-source', source).then(() => {
                 this.map_widget.mapbox.addLayer({
                        'id': 'layer-1',
                        'source': 'my-source',
                        'type': 'circle',
                        'paint': {
                            'circle-radius': 10,
                            'circle-color': '#eee'
                        }
                    });

                })
```

Now, I'd like to update the coordinates of the source but I couldn't find a way to look it up back.

Comment: Could you post some source code please?

Comment: First, thanks @MichaelSchönbauer for taking time to reply. I've edited the post with a bit of code. Let me know if you need more.